# Statistically independence conditions for transformation

Tags: statistics, linear-transformations

Let $x\in \mathbb R^3$ be a Gaussian vector with $(\mu_x,\Sigma_x)$, and let $y=Ux$ where $U\in \mathbb R^{3\times 3}$. What are the minimum conditions on $U$ so that $y$'s columns will be statistically independent? if $U$ is diagonal is that enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $U$ diagonal is only enough if $\Sigma_x$ is already diagonal. If it has nonzero off diagonal entries this means two or more entries of $x$ are correlated and therefore not independent.

So we need the covariance matrix $\Sigma_y$ of $y$ to be diagonal.

So for our minimal condition on $U$ would be that $\Sigma_y = U\Sigma_xU^{-t}$ is diagonal. In fact this condition is *equivalent* to the entries of $y$ to be independent.

There is actually an easy way to determine such an $U$: Since $\Sigma_x$ is a covariance matrix, it is symmetric and positive semidefinite. This means we can factor $\Sigma_x = LDL^t$ uniquely where $L$ is a lower (left) triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal, and $D$ is diagonal. If we set $y = L^{-t} x$  (i.e. $U=L^{-1}$ we see that $y$ has $D$ as covariance matrix.

Comment: Isn't $\Sigma_y =U\Sigma_x U^T$ a in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509238/expected-value-matrix-properties)?

Comment: Yes it is indeed.

Comment: No, $U$ does not have to be symmetric or positive semidefinite.

Comment: I think I got it, $U^{-1}$ has to be triangular with ones on the diagonal.

Comment: If you use the $L$ given by this decomposition of SPD matrices, you can also scale it with a diagonal matrix, and the entries of $y$ remain independent.